# Create a nonclustered non-unique index within the CREATE TABLE statement with SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

It is possible to create a primary key or unique index within a SQL Server CREATE TABLE statement. Is it possible to create a **non-unique** index within a CREATE TABLE statement?

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable(
    a int NOT NULL
    ,b smallint NOT NULL
    ,c smallint NOT NULL
    ,d smallint NOT NULL
    ,e smallint NOT NULL

    -- This creates a primary key
    ,CONSTRAINT PK_MyTable PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (a)

    -- This creates a unique nonclustered index on columns b and c
    ,CONSTRAINT IX_MyTable1 UNIQUE (b, c)

    -- Is it possible to create a non-unique index on columns d and e here?
    -- Note: these variations would not work if attempted:
    -- ,CONSTRAINT IX_MyTable2 INDEX (d, e)
    -- ,CONSTRAINT IX_MyTable3 NONCLUSTERED INDEX (d, e)
);
GO

-- The proposed non-unique index should behave identically to
-- an index created after the CREATE TABLE statement. Example:
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_MyTable4 ON MY_TABLE (d, e);
GO
```

Again, the goal is to create the non-unique index within the CREATE TABLE statement, not after it.

For what it's worth, I did not find the [[SQL Server Books Online entry for CREATE TABLE]](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174979.aspx) to be helpful.

Also, [[This Question]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2689930/how-to-create-nonclustered-index-in-create-table) is nearly identical, but the accepted answer does not apply.

Answer (score 182, accepted):

As of SQL 2014, this can be accomplished via [inline index creation](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/t-sql/statements/create-table-transact-sql#full-syntax):

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable(
    a int NOT NULL
    ,b smallint NOT NULL
    ,c smallint NOT NULL
    ,d smallint NOT NULL
    ,e smallint NOT NULL

    -- This creates a primary key
    ,CONSTRAINT PK_MyTable PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (a)

    -- This creates a unique nonclustered index on columns b and c
    ,CONSTRAINT IX_MyTable1 UNIQUE (b, c)

    -- This creates a standard non-clustered index on (d, e)
    ,INDEX IX_MyTable4 NONCLUSTERED (d, e)
);
GO
```

---

Prior to SQL 2014, CREATE/ALTER TABLE only accepted CONSTRAINTs to be added, not indexes. The fact that primary key and unique constraints are implemented in terms of an index is a side effect.

Comment: Thanks for the great explanation! Why? Purely for aesthetic reasons. I thought it could be convenient to anyone reading the script if all constraints/indexes are contained within the same statement. Personally, I like to know whether columns belonging to a foreign key also have an index, and this may have been a nice method to logically group this information in the same statement.

Comment: I got `Error: (1146) Table 'tablename' doesn't exist`, hahahah, ironic

Comment: Is it possible for this index to have `INCLUDE`ed columns?

Comment: Getting this Error:  Msg 1018, Level 15, State 1, Line 15
Incorrect syntax near 'INDEX'. If this is intended as a part of a table hint, A WITH keyword and parenthesis are now required. See SQL Server Books Online for proper syntax.

Answer (score 25):

**TLDR:**

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable(
    a int NOT NULL
    ,b smallint NOT NULL index IX_indexName nonclustered
    ,c smallint NOT NULL
    ,d smallint NOT NULL
    ,e smallint NOT NULL
)
```

**Details**

As per [T-SQL CREATE TABLE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174979.aspx) documentation, in 2014 the column definition supports defining an index:

```
<column_definition> ::=  
column_name <data_type>  
    ...
    [ <column_index> ]
```

and <column_index> grammar is defined as:

```
<column_index> ::=   
 INDEX index_name [ CLUSTERED | NONCLUSTERED ]  
    [ WITH ( <index_option> [ ,... n ] ) ]  
    [ ON { partition_scheme_name (column_name )   
         | filegroup_name  
         | default   
         }  
    ]   
    [ FILESTREAM_ON { filestream_filegroup_name | partition_scheme_name | "NULL" } ]
```

So a lot of what you can do as a separate statement can be done inline.  I noticed `include` is not an option in this grammar so some things are not possible.

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable(
    a int NOT NULL
    ,b smallint NOT NULL index IX_indexName nonclustered
    ,c smallint NOT NULL
    ,d smallint NOT NULL
    ,e smallint NOT NULL
)
```

You can also have inline indexes defined as another line after columns, but within the create table statement, and this allows multiple columns in the index, but still no `include` clause:

```
< table_index > ::=   
{  
    {  
      INDEX index_name [ CLUSTERED | NONCLUSTERED ]   
         (column_name [ ASC | DESC ] [ ,... n ] )   
    | INDEX index_name CLUSTERED COLUMNSTORE  
    | INDEX index_name [ NONCLUSTERED ] COLUMNSTORE (column_name [ ,... n ] )  
    }  
    [ WITH ( <index_option> [ ,... n ] ) ]   
    [ ON { partition_scheme_name (column_name )   
         | filegroup_name  
         | default   
         }  
    ]   
    [ FILESTREAM_ON { filestream_filegroup_name | partition_scheme_name | "NULL" } ]  
  
}
```

For example here we add an index on both columns c and d:

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable(
    a int NOT NULL
    ,b smallint NOT NULL index IX_MyTable_b nonclustered
    ,c smallint NOT NULL
    ,d smallint NOT NULL
    ,e smallint NOT NULL

    ,index IX_MyTable_c_d nonclustered (c,d)
)
```

Comment: This works great, and according to BOL it goes back to 2008 at least. Like the OP, I find the code I mostly see (usually generated by SSMS) makes my eyeballs hurt, and I just like my table definitions to make sense for a rational human. Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

It's a separate statement.

It's also not possible to insert into a table and select from it and build an index in the same statement either.

The BOL entry contains the information you need:

> CLUSTERED | NONCLUSTERED
>   Indicate that
>   a clustered or a nonclustered index is
>   created for the PRIMARY KEY or UNIQUE
>   constraint. PRIMARY KEY constraints
>   default to CLUSTERED, and UNIQUE
>   constraints default to NONCLUSTERED.
>
> In a CREATE TABLE statement, CLUSTERED
>   can be specified for only one
>   constraint. If CLUSTERED is specified
>   for a UNIQUE constraint and a PRIMARY
>   KEY constraint is also specified, the
>   PRIMARY KEY defaults to NONCLUSTERED.

You can create an index on a PK field, but not a non-clustered index on a non-pk non-unique-constrained field.

A NCL index is not relevant to the structure of the table, and is not a constraint on the data inside the table.  It's a separate entity that supports the table but is not integral to it's functionality or design.

That's why it's a separate statement.  The NCL index is irrelevant to the table from a design perspective (query optimization notwithstanding).

Answer (score 7):

The accepted answer of how to create an **Index** inline a Table creation script did not work for me.  This did:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TableToBeCreated]
(
    [Id] BIGINT IDENTITY(1, 1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
    ,[ForeignKeyId] BIGINT NOT NULL
    ,CONSTRAINT [FK_TableToBeCreated_ForeignKeyId_OtherTable_Id] FOREIGN KEY ([ForeignKeyId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[OtherTable]([Id])
    ,INDEX [IX_TableToBeCreated_ForeignKeyId] NONCLUSTERED ([ForeignKeyId])
)
```

Remember, Foreign Keys do not create Indexes, so it is good practice to index them as you will more than likely be joining on them.

Comment: I'm not following that last statement.  I would agree with that statement if it's usual practise to query your table by the foreign key; but not simply that you join on it therefore it should be indexed.  Example: Find all employees and their company name of company id X - then sure an index on the FK helps.  Find all employees and their company name with last name starting with A; index on the FK doesn't help.  In other words, I'm not sure that "because you join on it you should index it" is good practise.  Am I missing something?

Comment: Indexes make join queries faster.