# How to create a table with index in one sql sentence

Tags: sql

I want to create a table with Index. Generally speaking, I can do that in two sentences:

```
create table if not exists my_table
create index if not exists my_index on my_table (my_column ASC)
```

I wonder, could I do that in one sentence? Like:

```
create table if not exists my_table with index if not exists my_index (my_column ASC)
```

Comment: which database you are using ?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6193293/create-a-nonclustered-non-unique-index-within-the-create-table-statement-with-sq

Comment: @AmeyaDeshpande , I use sqlite