# How do I make two foreign keys a primary key?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, foreign-keys, create-table

My table MealIng has two foreign keys from two other tables that I want to make primary key. How do I specify this?

This is my code. What do I need to change to get this to work?

```
CREATE TABLE Meals (
    MealID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    Meal TEXT,
    Type TEXT
);

CREATE TABLE Ing (
    IngID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
IngName TEXT,
    UnitCost NUMERIC
);

CREATE TABLE MealIng (
MealID INTEGER FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Meal(MealID),
    IngID INTEGER FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Ing(IngID),
    Quantity INTEGER
);
```

Comment: Add `, CONSTRAINT PK_MealIng PRIMARY KEY (MealId, IngId)` at the end of the table definition.  See the `<table_constraint>` section in [CREATE TABLE (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-table-transact-sql).

Comment: There must be a duplicate question somewhere

Comment: It's one of those questions where the answer seems obvious, *but only after you already know the answer*.

Comment: As a noob I built an app where a macro deleted all the data to roll over from one year to the next because I didn’t understand compound keys.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft As a *seasoned* programmer, I once coded `DELETE FROM Orgs WHERE OrgId IN (SELECT OrgId FROM @OrgsToDelete)`, along with all dependent deletes. Trouble was: `the @OrgsToDelete` table-var only contained an `OrgName`. Interestingly, it was still valid code, and SQL Server found a way to make it work. My manager was in a rush to apply this to production without proper testing, and I was late for my daughter's birthday party, so I left it in his hands. Reportedly took an unusually long time to run. (Grin) Final nail was when the transaction logs got purged at midnight. Fun.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
CREATE TABLE MealIng 
(
    MealID INTEGER NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Meal(MealID),
    IngID INTEGER NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Ing(IngID),
    Quantity INTEGER,
    CONSTRAINT PK_MealIng PRIMARY KEY (MealId, IngId),
    INDEX IX_MealIng_IngID (IngID)
)
```

See the <table_constraint> section in [CREATE TABLE (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-table-transact-sql)

And you generally want an index supporting each foreign key for lookups and cascading deletes.  The PK supports the MealID FK, but you need a secondary index to support the IngID FK.

Comment: Indices can be included into the `create table`? I must have missed that. Strangely enough, SSDT doesn't script tables this way - it always creates separate `create index` statements. Learning new things every day...

Comment: Since SQL Server 2014 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6193293/create-a-nonclustered-non-unique-index-within-the-create-table-statement-with-sq